# programmatically render statically declared controls in aspx

Tags: asp.net, rendercontrol

I'm trying to programmatically render an aspx page to a string.
The rendering is to be done from a console app.
For now I've gotten it work with programmatically declared controls in the aspx page, which is all fine and dandy. 
But what about statically declared controls? It there any way to achieve that?

Example code:
Page rendering:

```
static string RenderPage() {

        ClassLibrary1.FormlessPage pageHolder = (ClassLibrary1.FormlessPage)new WebApplication1.WebForm1();
        pageHolder.DesignerInitialize();

        StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
        HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", "http://localhost/", "");
        HttpResponse httpResponse = new HttpResponse(output);
        HttpContext context = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponse);
        context.Server.Execute(pageHolder, output, false);

        return output.ToString();
    }
```

Formless page class

```
namespace ClassLibrary1 {
public class FormlessPage : System.Web.UI.Page {
    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control) {}
}
}
```

Now, when I declare controls in WebForm1 (which is in a references web application project, but behavior is the same when done within the same project) they render just fine.

```
public partial class WebForm1 : ClassLibrary1.FormlessPage {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { ID = "tbSomeText", Text = "default text" });
    }
}
```

...but static html and statically declared controls are not rendered.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
...blah...blah...
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    text
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbSomething"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
</form>
...blah...blah...
```

Is there any way to completely fake this behavior and achieve the markup rendering too?
Rendered output from the above is simply:

```
<input name="tbSomeText" type="text" value="default text" id="tbSomeText" />
```

Comment: Are you sure you'er calling the right page? Does it render the controls when you open it in a browser?

Comment: Do doubt about it. Everything works as expected when viewed in a browser.